# Webpack-Cli dependency error in asp.net core 2.0 compilation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, webpack, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a asp.net core react app and using webpack for bundling .I have installed required dependencies but when build application it shows an error.

How could i resolve this error.

I have installed required dependencies so many times done npm cache clean and restarted a machine.still its showing not installed in vs solution explorer.

[image]

webpack installed in requied folder.

IN vs solution

[image]

[image]
when try to restore package inside solution explorer,its not installed.

[image]

webpack-cli is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doing wrong in your npm install

Should be this command for global

```
npm i -g webpack-cli
```

or this command for local

```
npm i -D webpack-cli
```

You can not mix up between -D -g flag

If that didn't work for you try to right click on that package and click restore

Update:

Try to delete package-lock.json then run npm i -D webpack-cli again

Comment: Can you find webpack-cli in your node_modules folder ?

Comment: no webpack is there ,webpack-cli is not in folder , i have updated a question, clear the node cache and try to install globally and as well as locally still have an issue.

Comment: Try to delete package-lock.json then run `npm i -D webpack-cli` again